# Eloquent Laravel 5 - Many to many relation with multi column with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many

I use: Laravel mongodb (https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)

I have table relation in MySQL

table: *apps*

```
ID
Name
```

table: *clients*

```
ID
Name
```

And table relationship: *app_client*

```
app_id
client_id
version
```

field '*version*' in table *app_client* is string type

**How to create relational tables in MongoDB as containing the *version* column?**

I create table in Mongodb:
table: *apps*

```
ID
Name
client_ids => is array: [ObjectID('client_id'), ObjectID('client_id')]
```

table: *clients*

```
ID
Name
app_ids => is array: [ObjectID('app_id'), ObjectID('app_id')]
```

My Eloquent (Model Client):

```
public function apps(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Model\App', null, 'client_ids', 'app_ids');
}
```

But, not column *version*
Do you know what I mean? How to create column *version* in database mongodb for Eloquent?